# Why am I able to run PHP sudo commands?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I have a PHP script that does the following:

```
$output = exec('sudo nginx -t 2>&1');
echo $output;
```

As expected, it returns the following due to using a `sudo` command:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

However, I am able to run PHP in the terminal `php /var/www/html/script.php` and it works without being prompted for a sudo password.

Someone has told me that I am running PHP as a root on my system, which is dangerous.

However, all I did was follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04) - is it really that dangerous?

Also, if I use a **Cron job** to run the PHP script, it runs perfectly

I am using NGINX with Ubuntu 20.04 + PHP 7

Comment: PHP is running as the webserver user and can't prompt for a password with no tty or askpass.  In the terminal you are running it as whatever user you loggedin as.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Running it from a normal user account (not root) and without the `sudo` command makes it work. Also, if I set up a Cron job to run that PHP script, that also works - is that expected? Or is it because my PHP is running as **root** which is supposedly dangerous

Comment: What happens if you just do `exec('/path/to/nginx -t 2>&1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `php /var/www/html/script.php`, you run the `php` process under your current user (that is most probably in the `sudoers` group).

Ubuntu default sudo password timeout is 15 minutes. Which means, if your user (the one who also runs the PHP script) has entered sudo password less than 15 minutes ago, the system won't ask for it again.

Comment: Running a cron job makes it work also, is that expected?

Comment: Depends on which user runs the cron job. If it's root (not recommended), it will always run the priviledged (sudo) script successfully. If it's your user, it should follow the 15-minute rule.

Comment: @PetrHejda What's wrong with running CRONs from root?

Comment: @user3783243 It's simply more risky. Root user has more permissions than regular user so it is able to damage other parts of the system if the script that you run has a flaw.